# Adobe Dynamic link between PremierPro and AfterEffects is not working

Tags: adobe, after-effects, adobe-premiere

When I work with video editing `Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014`,when i right click on the video after adding the video to timeline ,I look for  `replace with aftereffect composition` but option is disabled .

I google for the solution the said to add the shortcuts of files in the `dynamiclink` folder which is in the path of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\dynamiclink` but I do not find that folder.

So I made one like folder as they said and tried but that did not solve my problem.

## Softwares I Use

1. **Adobe After Effects CC 2015**
2. **Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014**

---

Hope I explained the problem in clear if not please mention in comments id you need any further information
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey I also faced this problem,I found a solution in the youtube and I followed the following steps hope this helps you ,it worked for me but it may or may not works for you based on your `configuration`

The First feasible solution is as follows

1. Prepare shortcuts for the both softwares `Adobe Premiere Pro cc
   2014` & `Adobe After Effects cc 2015` by going to their respective
   folders in the desktop
2. Copy those `shortcuts`.
3. Look for `dynamiclink` folder in the directory `C:\Program Files
   x86\Common Files\Adobe\dynamiclink` if the folder is not present
   prepare one with the same name `dynamiclink`.
4. Now paste those `shortcuts` into the folder.
5. Now refresh and `restart` the application.

If problem persists again ,then the problem is due to incompatability of the versions you are trying to link dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured the solution
When I Upgraded to `Adobe Premiere Pro cc 2015` The Dynamic link is perfectly working
The problem is with the versions of development

Upgrade from

> Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014 to Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015

Comment: That make sense, if the softs are not on the same version, there would be compatibility issues

Comment: @KevinM Ya you are absolutely right.But I do not know that before I just tried with latest version It worked finally.